# how gcp cli works internally to stop instances

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, gcloud

Team i need to know how **gcp compute instances stop [instance name]** command works internally.
Need to know it does graceful shutdown or non graceful shutdown?

Also need to know ,is there any way via cli we can do non graceful (VM)shutdown?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface

Answer (score 0):

That command could be considered as a grateful shutdown if the VM responds appropiately. If in a given time frame it doesn't, it will be forced to shutdown. I don't think there is a way to do a non-grateful, forced shutdown without attempting a ACPI signal first.

> Stopping a VM causes Compute Engine to send the ACPI shutdown signal to the VM. Modern guest operating systems (OS) are configured to perform a clean shutdown before powering off in response to the power off signal. Compute Engine waits a short time for the guest OS to finish shutting down and then transitions the VM to the TERMINATED state.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/stop